# for $ F(x,y) = 10$, what is $ y'$?

Tags: analysis, implicit-differentiation

For an input $x$ and output $y$ of a system it is know that $x,y$ always satisfy

$$ F(x,y) = 10 $$

At a certain point, $x=1$ and $y=1$. The question is how $y$ responds to a small decrease in $x$, e.g. to $ 0.999$ (that is, what is $y'(x)$ of the function $y(x)$ near $x=1$.

Now this somehow asks for an application of the Implicat Function Theorem, of a Taylor Polynomial, or both of them.

Intuitively, as $F(x,y) = 10$, can I not simply conclude that each decrease in $x$ has to be compensated by a change in $\Delta y =-x$, in order to keep $F(x,y)$ constant again?
However, on economic grounds, a decrease in inputs resulting in an increase in output sounds kind of awkward.

So I summed up what I know again:

$$F(1,1) = 10 $$

$$ F(0.999, 1 + y'(1)) = 10 $$

$$ y'(1) = - \frac{\frac{\partial{F}}{x}(1,1)}{\frac{\partial{F}}{y}(1,1)}
$$

But there I'm stuck - how to solve when both $F$ and $y$ are unknown?

Thanks for all hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use total differential. If $F(x,y)$ is constant it means that 
$$dF=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}dy=0$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=y'=-\frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}}$$
In economics it makes sense since it is an implicit function. Assume that the production function is given such as
$$y=x^2+10 \Rightarrow F(x,y)=y-x^2=10$$
and
$$y'=-\frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}}=-\frac{-2x}{1}=2x$$
which shows output will increase as a result of an input increase.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from notation, your solution is correct and complete:
$$y'(1)=-\frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(1,1)}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(1,1)}.$$